# Problema con variable dentro de un trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo un trigger **before insert** en tabla **detalleventa** para que cuando se inserte un registro se complete la columna **total**, que es el resultado de **precio** * **cantidad**

- Estructura de tablas:

**producto:** codigo(varchar 45), nombre(varchar 255), precio(decimal 10,2), stock(int 11), estado(varchar 1)

Llave primaria codigo.

**detalleventa:** idventa(int 11), codproducto(varchar 45), cantidad(int 11), total(decimal 10,2)

Llave primaria compuesta por idventa y codproducto.

- Trigger:

```
begin

declare precio decimal(10,2);
set precio =(select precio from producto where 
 codigo =new.codproducto);
set new.total =(precio * new.cantidad);

end
```

Pero al insertar, el campo **total** queda **nulo**.

La consulta select esta probada y funciona.
El problema esta en la **variable precio**, ¿estará mal declarada?

Comment: Creo que te podrias evitar el problema del triggrer y usar una columna de tipo computada como en SQL Server en MySql se llaman Generated Columns, asi se calcula sola sin necesidad de un trigger 
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/#:~:text=MySQL%205.7%20introduced%20a%20new,computed%20based%20on%20predefined%20expressions.

Comment: @EdgarVazquez lo voy a probar, gracias por ese dato!

Comment: @EdgarVazquez está interesante ese Generated Columns pero no me sirve por que el precio lo tengo que traer de otra tabla (producto). Ese esta muy bueno para el caso que los datos a calcular esten en la misma tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está que la variable local `precio` dentro del disparador (trigger) se identifica (se llama) igual a la columna `precio` de la tabla `producto`, aplicando la siguiente regla de precedencia:

> [25.8 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routine-name-conflicts)
>
> ...
>
> - A local variable takes precedence over a routine parameter or table column.
>
> ...

Disculpar pero la documentación está en inglés, pero seria algo como:

> - Una variable local tiene prioridad sobre un parámetro de rutina o una columna de tabla.

Puede intantar lo siguiente como una opción:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_bi_detalleventa`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bi_detalleventa` BEFORE INSERT ON `detalleventa`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE `_precio` DECIMAL(10, 2);

  SET
    `_precio` := (
      SELECT `precio`
      FROM `producto`
      WHERE `codigo` = NEW.`codproducto`
    ),
    NEW.`total` := `_precio` * NEW.`cantidad`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa3524411aaf2469ec4fc06edf618a45).